# PKCanvasView How to get position and pressure in iOS 13 [objC]?

Tags: ios, objective-c, position, pressure, pencilkit

i want to get data of each point position and pressure which have been painted in PKCanvasView, i have tried `touchesBegan` with kept user interaction enabled and gesture Recognisers but none of it worked for me. If there is any other solution to track these values for iPencil then guide me.

Comment: any luck ? i am stuck with the same.